# JQuery Catch onChange event of EditableField - datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii, datepicker

Hi i'm having a problem of catching event of an editable field.

I'm using Yii php, and i use the extension editablefield from x-editable.

```
$this->widget('ext.editable.EditableField', array(
    'type'      => 'date',
    'value' => $data->date_of_harvest,
    'model'     => $data,
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'id' => $data->id,
        'class' => 'harvest-datepicker',  
    ),
    'attribute' => 'date_of_harvest',
    'emptytext' => "<i class='icon-plus-sign'/></i><span>Add</span>"
));
```

Above is my widget - just a simple datepicker. However i can't seem to catch the change event of it. I tried below:

```
$(".harvest-datepicker").change(function(){

    console.log("test");
    var progenyId = $(this).attr('id');
    var value = $(this).val();

});
```

but that doesn't seem to do the trick. It doesnt even go inside the event function. Any help would do thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery reads for first event only so what ever will be called firstly it will work and another call will not so you have to bind both the script on single event. There is no other way.

Comment: like if you want onclick of a button you need to change its text as well as you want to submit a form you need to do like this
<button id="btn">Submit</button>
$("#btn").click(function(){
$(this).text("Submitting");
$("#form_id").submit();
});

Here i have added two events for submitting a form and changing the text of button. In same manner you have to call the datepicker function inside your editable js when it is called.